# How might the hypothetical "Dyson sphere" convert the energy from the sun to usable electricity?

Tags: energy, thermoelectricity

I have tried to find the answer but it appears that this question was never asked. I consulted my teachers but they do not have any knowledge of this either.

Comment: [The same way we do it on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_power).

Comment: have you searched with google? here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP44EPBMb8A

Comment: In most designs we tend to assume photovoltaics, although solar thermal is the model in (Badscu 1995) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/009457659500009O